# pyspark aggregation with udf for each row value

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am very much new to pyspark and my problem is as follows:

I have this sample data frame and I want to apply `withColumn(avg coeff)` to each row of country column having same value (in country) and give me an output.

This is my selfmade dataframe similar to what I have been actually working on:

```
+--------+--------+---+-----+----+----+-----+------------+---------+----+
|Relegion| Country|Day|Month|Year|Week|cases|Weekly Coeff|Avg Coeff|rank|
+--------+--------+---+-----+----+----+-----+------------+---------+----+
|   Hindu|   India|  3|    1|  20|   1|   30|         0.5|    0.616|   3|
|   Hindu|   India|  2|    1|  20|   1|   20|         0.7|    0.616|   3|
|   Hindu|   India|  5|    2|  20|   2|  100|         0.9|    0.616|   3|
|   Hindu|   India|  6|    2|  20|   2|  160|         0.4|    0.616|   3|
|   Hindu|   India|  6|    2|  20|   1|  160|         0.4|    0.616|   3|
|   Hindu|   India|  1|    1|  20|   2|    5|         0.6|    0.616|   3|
|   Hindu|   India|  1|    1|  20|   1|    5|         0.6|    0.616|   3|
|   Hindu|   India|  2|    1|  20|   2|   20|         0.7|    0.616|   3|
|   Hindu|   India|  4|    2|  20|   1|   10|         0.6|    0.616|   3|
|   Hindu|   India|  3|    1|  20|   2|   30|         0.5|    0.616|   3|
|   Hindu|   India|  4|    2|  20|   2|   10|         0.6|    0.616|   3|
|   Hindu|   India|  5|    2|  20|   1|  100|         0.9|    0.616|   3|
|  Muslim|Pakistan|  1|    1|  20|   1|  100|         0.6|    0.683|   2|
|  Muslim|Pakistan|  4|    2|  20|   1|  200|         0.6|    0.683|   2|
|  Muslim|Pakistan|  2|    1|  20|   1|   20|         0.9|    0.683|   2|
|  Muslim|Pakistan|  5|    2|  20|   1|  300|         0.8|    0.683|   2|
|  Muslim|Pakistan|  2|    1|  20|   2|   20|         0.9|    0.683|   2|
|  Muslim|Pakistan|  3|    1|  20|   1|   50|         0.4|    0.683|   2|
|  Muslim|Pakistan|  6|    2|  20|   1|  310|         0.8|    0.683|   2|
|  Muslim|Pakistan|  3|    1|  20|   2|   50|         0.4|    0.683|   2|
+--------+--------+---+-----+----+----+-----+------------+---------+----+
```

I have to find the average coefficient (one value per country), I have added a column manually to test the result I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use average over a window:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn('Avg_coeff', F.avg('Weekly_coeff').over(Window.partitionBy('Country')))
```

Note that it's not a good practice to have spaces in column names.